# Search nested object for property

Tags: php

I have an object being returned from an API and i need to see if a property exists. Problem is the properties could be other objects, each of which would need to be searched.

This is probably solved with recursion but i cant get my head around it or my code examples to work.

I'm amazed that i cant find a solution to this online so posting here for expert advice.

This is an example of an object, i need to make sure that "LowestNewPrice" exists and have the value returned

```
stdClass Object
(
    [OperationRequest] => stdClass Object
        (
            [HTTPHeaders] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Header] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Name] => UserAgent
                            [Value] => PHP-SOAP/5.6.2
                        )

                )

            [RequestId] => 20bd3916-3d92-4519-b3be-c80c7cf16b1b
            [Arguments] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Argument] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Name] => Service
                            [Value] => AWSECommerceService
                        )

                )

            [RequestProcessingTime] => 0.005986476
        )

    [Items] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Request] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [IsValid] => True
                    [ItemLookupRequest] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [IdType] => ASIN
                            [ItemId] => 1405278269
                            [ResponseGroup] => OfferSummary
                            [VariationPage] => All
                        )

                )

            [Item] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ASIN] => 1405278269
                    [OfferSummary] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [LowestNewPrice] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 44
                                    [CurrencyCode] => GBP
                                    [FormattedPrice] => £0.44
                                )

                            [LowestUsedPrice] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Amount] => 1
                                    [CurrencyCode] => GBP
                                    [FormattedPrice] => £0.01
                                )

                            [TotalNew] => 30
                            [TotalUsed] => 12
                            [TotalCollectible] => 0
                            [TotalRefurbished] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to rome..

```
$findInObject = function($obj,$property) use (&$findInObject){
    if(is_object($obj)){
        $obvar = get_object_vars($obj);
        if(array_key_exists($property,$obvar)){
            return $obvar[$property];
        } else {
            foreach($obvar as $var){
                $result =  $findInObject($var,$property);
                if($result){
                    return $result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
};

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->MyProp1 = new stdClass();
$obj->MyProp1b = new stdClass();
$obj->MyProp1->MyProp2 = 'myresult';
$obj->MyProp1->MyProp2b = 'myresultb';


print_r($findInObject($obj,'MyProp2'));//Result: myresult
print_r($findInObject($obj,'MyProp2b'));//Result: myresultb
//OR 
print_r($findInObject($obj->MyProp1,'MyProp2b'));//Result: myresultb
```

Comment: Excellent - works like a charm. For my specific use, searching a json string is the best method but i have no doubt this will be useful in the future - thank you very much for posting.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `isset` for checking object property:

```
if(isset($response->Items->Item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice)) {
    // LowestNewPrice exists
} else {
    // Doesn't exist or one of the properties doesn't exist
}
```

This way, you don't need to check each property individually.

Answer (score 0):

As its always in the same place i'll use this

```
property_exists($response->Items->Item->OfferSummary,'LowestNewPrice')
```

Comment: All of the posted answers are decent EXCEPT for the accepted one! Please re-evaluate your decision for the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

1. Cast this object to json string
2. Use `strpos` to check if key exists if all  You need is to check if it is present or use `preg_match()` to search for pair `key=>value`

Comment: This is a horrible and unprofessional answer. No one should be converting a readily traversed data structure into a string then using a data-structure-ignorant tool like regex to try to parse the string representation of the data.  Sadly, I can only DV once, this warning is the only other thing that I can do to help researchers.